# What is Apple doing with UUCP?

Tags: macos, network, unix

I have been looking into UUCP ([Unix-to-Unix Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP), a very old network protocol) as a way of communicating with some Linux boxes that don't always have an internet connection. While doing so on my Macbook (with El Capitan), I found entries in my `/usr/share/uucp/sys` file for `uucpsys1.apple.com` and `uucpsys2.apple.com`. (You can also see these by running `uuchk | less`.)

What is Apple doing with UUCP? I found [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5997004?tstart=0) on the Apple forums by someone who noticed a UUCP user, but no one came forward with an explanation, so I'm hoping someone here will know.

I'm especially curious because `/usr/share/*` falls under System Integrity Protection in El Capitan, which means I'll need to set up a separate UUCP implementation if I want to use it for my purposes — but it also suggests that, if Apple's shipping OS X with a UUCP that only they can use, they must be using it for *something.*

*ETA:* I've also found a launchd daemon at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.uucp.plist`. It has `<key>Disabled</key><true/>` in the plist, so it won't be run by default, but other daemons could enable it programmatically without altering the plist. I'm also intrigued to see that it's in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/` (and thus subject to SIP) rather than `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` — it adds to my hunch that it's something Apple is using (or maybe was using, as patrix comments), rather than just a miscellaneous *nix tool they happened to include.

Comment: Apple is probably doing nothing with UUCP so they didn't even realize that SIP prevents anybody from using it.

Comment: Aside: if anyone else is trying to use UUCP on OS X, I figured out that you don't actually need to install an entirely separate implementation: all of the commands let you specify a different configuration file with `--config /usr/local/conf/uucp/config`, so you just need to create your own define log, spool, etc with that. `info uucp` was a big help.

Comment: Neither uucpsys1.apple.com nor uucpsys2.apple.com get resolved in DNS, so whatever it was, it's long gone (or only used internally by Apple).

Answer (score 1):

Those entries are examples that can be used as templates in user defined configurations.

See the same examples at:

```
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/uucp/uucp-11/configs/sys
```

You can see those examples in the same way as the phone prefix +555 in the movies. It there to show somebody using a phone, but the fake number/name cant be called. Placing an example with a ficticious hostname allows to have a template.